# Flask, SQLAlchemy and multithreading: MySQL too many connections

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm writing multithreading app using Flask + SQL Alchemy + MySQL.

SQL Alchemy settings:

```
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE = 200
SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW = 50
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 5
```

My app can running up to 300 threads simultaneously. In every thread there is some DB usage like:

```
# task == my model
db.session.add(task)

task.progress += 1
db.session.commit()
```

and some more complicated code

After 3-5 minutes of working my MySQL will gone away because of too many connections.
I've tried *db.session.close()* and *db.session.bind.dispose()* after every thread complete his work. But It doesnt help, in 3-5 minutes there will be 200+ connections and MySQL will die.

How to manage this connections proper?

Comment: If you need **300 separate connections** then there's no way around the problem. If you don't, you should lower the pool size. *You* are allowing SQLAlchemy to connect with that many (250) connections.

Comment: this constant SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE = 200 doesnt change anything. Even when it equal 200 actual mysql connections could be 800+

Comment: Then that means you have multiple pools, meaning you are using some kind of multiple processes. You need to lower it to (max number of processes MySQL can handle) / (number of processes you have).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way.

first go to your mysql server and change max_connections option.

set global max_connections=1000;